How to measure FLASK endpoint execution time, when this is streaming
I want to log the response time of a specific endpoint using AppInsights.
However my endpoint is streaming content because its using OpenAI LLM, so I need to measure the time at the end after the response is full generated.
@app.route('/policy', methods=['POST'])
def policy():
    
    """
    Endpoint to generate tokens based on a prompt for HR Documents

    Returns:
        Response: Response object containing generated tokens.

    """
    start_time = time()
   
    if authenticate_request():
        prompt = request.json.get("prompt", "What are argenx values?")
        chat_history = request.json.get("chat_history", "")
        username = request.json.get("username", "")
        
        inputs = [item.get('input') for item in chat_history]
        outputs = [item.get('output') for item in chat_history]

        #tc.track_trace(f"Generating tokens for HR prompt: {prompt}")

        def generate_tokens():
            g = policy_gpt_chain(prompt, username, inputs, outputs)
            try:
                while True:
                    token = next(g)
                    yield token
            except StopIteration:
                pass
            
       

        return Response(stream_with_context(generate_tokens()), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    else:
        #tc.track_trace("Unauthorized request.")
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized. Invalid or missing API key."}), 401

I tried adding this:
 @after_this_request
        def log_execution_time(response):
            end_time = time()
            execution_time = (end_time - start_time) * 1000  # Convert to milliseconds

            # Log custom event for endpoint execution time
            log_custom_event('PolicyEndpointExecutionTime', {'execution_time_ms': execution_time})
            return response

but thats executed inmediately and not at the end  of the response.

Have you tried teardown_request? Afaik, after_request is being called after the request but it's capable of modifying the response object. Maybe teardown_request is being called after request has been sent and completely finished.
